# Diffraction through fingers

Tags: visible-light, diffraction

I found two different versions of single slit diffraction through fingers [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.13140/2.1.3921.9526) and [here](https://www.slideserve.com/kibo-nelson/wave-nature-of-light) (12th slide).

[image]
[image]

Which one is correct?

I think there will be a spike perpendicular to the gap as in the first one but is it really possible to see the spectrum?

Comment: It always looks like the 2nd diagram to me. I've never seen the effects illustrated in the 1st diagram with the naked eye.

Comment: I verified this https://www.physicslens.com/single-slit-diffraction-using-fingers/ with my desk lamp.I do not get the effects of the picture on the left,

Comment: 1st photo looks like a lens effect to me.

Comment: @gs are you talking about [chromatic aberration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration)?